# selectively picking pattern free down values in the most efficient way: speed is an issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following problem, the code speaks for itself:

```
In[1]:= f[1][{1, 2}] = 112
Out[1]= 112
In[2]:= f[1][{3, 4}] = 114
Out[2]= 114
In[3]:= f[2][{1, 6}] = 216
Out[3]= 216
In[4]:= f[2][{2, 7}] = 227
Out[4]= 227
In[5]:= DownValues[f]
Out[5]= {}
In[6]:= SubValues[f]
Out[6]= {HoldPattern[f[1][{1, 2}]] :> 112, 
 HoldPattern[f[1][{3, 4}]] :> 114, HoldPattern[f[2][{1, 6}]] :> 216, 
 HoldPattern[f[2][{2, 7}]] :> 227}
In[7]:= SubValues[f[1]]
During evaluation of In[7]:= SubValues::sym: Argument f[1] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol. >>
Out[7]= SubValues[f[1]]
```

EDIT: the values above are not hard coded. They are constructed incrementally at run time. They are constructed using following algorithm:

```
f[_Integer][{_Integer..}] :=0
...
someplace later in the code, e.g.,
index = get index;
c = get random configuration (i.e. a pair of integers) = {n1, n2}; 
f[index][c] = f[index][c] + 1;
which tags that configuration c has occured once more in the simulation at time instance index
```

Please note that what happens in the last line is that the left hand side is not evaluated, the right hand side is, first the value for f[index][c] is looked up, if it is not found, then the defult rule is used which gives 0 + 1, if found the old value is incremented by one and stored. All this should be constant time. If one uses arrays, then it will be quadratic complexity (since whole array needs to be copied when one element is added).

The problem is that that, later on, I would like SubValues[f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti)] to give a list of definitions associated with f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti) that are pattern free but the syntax of SubValues forces me to retrieve all of them. Of course, this has later impact on the speed since one has to extract f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti)s of interest (e.g. in this example f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti)[{1, 2}] = 112, and f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti)[{3, 4}] = 114) from possibly a very long list.

Ultimatelly the problem is to harvest f[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti) data so that the following structure is returned:

```
{list1, list2}
```

where

```
list1 = {{1,2}, {3,4}}
list2 = {112, 134}
```

I know that one can use Cases[SubValues[f], suitablePattern] and work on the result to get the desired outcome, but I would like to do this more directly and in the most efficient way (since the procedure is repeated many times at runtime).

Regards
Zoran

EDIT: Seems that the problem was not well formulated. The better version of the the same problem can be found here:

[better formulated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256563/the-most-efficient-way-for-picking-pattern-free-downvalues-from-a-sparse-definiti)

so please "abandon the ship" and apologies for not being clear from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Why use SubValues?
It will always be the fastest if you put your information in a matrix, like:

```
m = { 
        {   {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {112, 114}   },
        {   {{1, 6}, {2, 7}}, {216, 227}   } 
     };
```

Then:

```
f[i_] := m[[i]];
f[1]
```

gives

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {112, 114}}
```

Comment: I agree, but I can't do that since these values are not hard coded. I just typed them in as an example. There is a sampling algorithm that fills these values and both the values (112, ...) and "keys" ({1,2}, {3,4}) can be anything and they are not know at runtime. They are actually added incrementally. In brief: the way these values are constructed enforces that they are stored as subvalues. The problem I am discussing has to do with the extraction part.

Comment: Of course, one could design a construction procedure that would work on the array level using some smart indexing but before doing that I would really like to be sure that there is no smart and efficient way to pick desired down values in the way I described. By all means, thanks for trying to help me.